# Correct URL syntax to use in : - URL url = new URL("url-goes-here");

Tags: android, url, inputstream

I am retrieving an image from a webpage (for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDQ9y.png ).

```
 InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
```

So i used the ip address instead of the domain name , but got no result.
Do i need to add the port no. also ? 
if yes what port to use ?

Answer (score 0):

IP should work, make sure your IP address is correct by opening image on browser first. The ip may be serving multiple site using virtual hosting.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html

> Equal IP addresses do not imply equal content. Virtual hosting permits
>   unrelated sites to share an IP address. This method could report two
>   otherwise unrelated URLs to be equal because they're hosted on the
>   same server.

Comment: i just used this site to convert domain name to ip address . is that okay ?

https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html

Comment: just replace the domain part of the full image url with the ip you got on that site and open it with your browser to test it.

Comment: oh well , i should have tested it before , it gives an error by the way ," Could not find the internal image you specified." . Any idea how can i get the ip address any other way ?
Even http://www.getip.com also gives the same ip address